# preg_match does not work

Tags: php, preg-match

This script checks if there is a special character or not, if there is, it calls for the preg match's "Invalid" function, else it says username available. What happens here is that every time I write a special character like #@%^& it still says username available instead of saying invalid, and that's not how it's supposed to work. I have checked the PHP code for errors and it seemed to be clean. I have tried and run to everything on forums and couldn't find a solution. Your contribution will be so much appreciated!

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);

    if(!empty($login)) {

        $login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `account` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
        $login_result = mysql_result($login_query,0);

        if($login_result == 0) {
           echo 'yes';
        } else {
           echo 'no';
        } 
    } 
 }

 if ( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/" , $login) )  {
    echo 'noinput'; 
 }
```

P.S I am not some kid who has leeched a code from the internet and is trying to get the others to do the work for him, I have written like 70% of this script and it works pretty well except the special characters thingy which I'm so stuck with. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: /[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/ Try this one, and say me if it works.

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs and expected outputs? Perhaps you should also do a `var_dump($login)` before the `preg_match`

Comment: When you escape the string, all the special characters become "good" characters...

Comment: @user2986690: You can verify Floris' comment by adding `var_dump($login);` before the `preg_match()` statement. You're escaping the input too soon. You should only do it *just* before inserting it into the database.

Comment: Can you show the code that actually determines whether the user name is available? Your `preg_match` code runs _after_ you have checked in the database, and printed "yes" or "no". What else happens?

Comment: @user2986690: Try the following: http://pastie.org/8907286

Comment: @user2986690, SO questions remain as a reference for anyone encountering similar problems in the future. You shouldn't try to hide your question once you get an answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is. I just wrote the following program:

```
<?php

$input="good string";
$input2="bad@string";

if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/",$input2)) {
  echo $input2." matches\n";
}
else {
  echo $input2." does not match\n";
}
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/",$input)) {
  echo $input." matches\n";
}
else {
  echo $input." does not match\n";
}
```

And it correctly shows that `$input` matches, but `$input2` does not.

Are you sure of what is in your input? Could there be a carriage return?

**update** I think it is simply a case of you misinterpreting the return values of the php script.  Let's look at the options:

1) valid username, is available:
query is empty, print string "yes". The `preg_match` finds a match and prints "noinput".

2) valid username, not available:
query returns something, print string "no". `preg_match` prints "noinput"

3) invalid username, is available:
query is empty, print string "yes". The `preg_match` prints nothing.

4) invalid username, not available:
query returns something, prints string "no". `preg_match` prints nothing.

If that is not how you interpret the return values, that's your problem...

**second update**

I have just looked at the source code of your link, and this is indeed the problem.  You seem to test for several different responses:

```
  if(data=='no') {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // something else
    });
  }
  if(data=='noinput') {
    // more stuff
    });
  }
  if(data=='invalid') {
    // yet more stuff
  });
```

In other words, you check for strings `'yes', 'no', 'noinput'`. But the way your code is structured and run, this is not the output you produce. For which I refer you to the four cases above.

**solution**

You need to move the check for invalid inputs to earlier in the code; and you need to return immediately after finding a user name that does not match. I think the following will work:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);

    if ( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/" , $login) )  
    {

        $login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `account` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
        $login_result = mysql_result($login_query,0);

        if($login_result == 0) 
        {
           echo 'yes';
        } 
        else 
        {
           echo 'no';
        } 
    }
    else
    {
       echo('noinput');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry you can't have my skype - that's not how this site works. But if you post further comments to this answer, I will be notified. And if I have time, I might respond.

Comment: Anyway to hide this? Floris please edit this I'm pleasing you (:

Comment: @user2986690 - There's not a lot that's unique about this bit of code. If you can anonymize variables, etc., that would be greatly preferred to the outright destruction of this content. It's not fair to those who answered and to future visitors to delete your questions once you got an answer.

Comment: @user2986690 I am sorry to see that you wanted to delete my answer. Realize that once you post something online, "it is forever". Even if we deleted the post, the edit history is still there. Not sure who you believe your "competitors" are, but as Brad pointed out, your code is not that special. As a gesture, I took out the "snapshot of code" from your link as it is actually irrelevant to my answer. But attempting to delete an answer by suggesting a heavy edit is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear your regular expression accounts for special characters. You'll need to add in the characters you want to catch outside of numbers and alpha.

Look here for some advice: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Try something like `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\$[:space:]]+$/`

The `\$` accounts for the literal character.

Comment: You said in your original post that you DON'T want special characters permitted, but then in another comment you say these ARE permitted. Which is it?